# Change a URL when you click on it

Tags: php, html, post, get

In my index.html there is a URL with an image.

So I want when you click on the image URL, the URL behind the image is permanent changed.

I tried it with GET and POST but I can't find a solution.

Would be nice if someone gives me an answer.

Comment: This can be achieved with Javascript/jQuery. Share some of your code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide more information, including your HTML/CSS relevant code and at best an example of how your web application should responds.

Comment: What do you mean by permanently changed? You want to change it for all other users, too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

script to be added

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
```

html code:

```
<img src="some_img.png" class="menulink" id="bg"/>
```

jquery code:

```
$(function() {
 $('.menulink').click(function(){
   $("#bg").attr('src',"img/picture1.jpg");
   return false;
 });
});
```